# Django: activate() not showing effect

Tags: python, django, django-timezone

I have the following line in `python manager.py shell`:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> zone = "Asia/Kolkata"
>>> timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(zone))
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 17, 1, 52, 0, 411937, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

But the output which I get is still using `UTC`. Should not it be converted into "Asia/Kolkata"?

**UPDATE**

If i use commands suggested by `dazedconfused` below:

```
zone = "Asia/Kolkata"
if zone:
    timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(zone))
else:
    timezone.deactivate()
utc_date = datetime.utcnow()
aware_date = timezone.make_aware(utc_date, timezone.utc)
l_time = timezone.localtime(aware_date, timezone.get_current_timezone())
```

And now when i try to save it on my database(Mongodb on Mongolab) it gets saved as `UTC`
I have a `DateTimeField` in my database.

Although when i save it as a simple string it gets saved in current timezone that is "Asia/kolkata" Output as string: `2014-12-17 11:01:53.028852+05:30`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually successfully sets the current time zone to "Asia/Kolkata"

You can verify by:

```
...
>>> timezone.get_current_timezone_name()
'Asia/Kolkata'
```

From the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now):

> now():
>
> Returns a datetime that represents the current point in time. Exactly
>   what’s returned depends on the value of USE_TZ:
>
> - If USE_TZ is False, this will be a naive datetime (i.e. a datetime
>     without an associated timezone) that represents the current time in
>     the system’s local timezone.
> - If USE_TZ is True, this will be an aware
>     datetime representing the current time in UTC. Note that **now() will
>     always return times in UTC regardless of the value of TIME_ZONE**; you
>     can use localtime() to convert to a time in the current time zone.

So, if your system's local timezone is 'Asia/Kolkata', you can set `USE_TZ` to `False` in your `settings.py` and the `timezone.now()` will return what you want.

Or, you'll have to use [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) to convert the timezone to yours (continue from your shell results):

```
...
>>> import datetime
>>> utc_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> aware_date = timezone.make_aware(utc_date, timezone.utc)
>>> timezone.localtime(aware_date, timezone.get_current_timezone())
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 17, 8, 0, 36, 598113, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Kolkata' IST+5:30:00 STD>)
```

Lastly, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware)'s the documentation of the `make_aware()` function